# Like Button customization

Tags: facebook-like

I'm trying to implement the Facebook Like button into a site and basically what I want is a very simple button that when clicked likes the corresponding facebook page and then opens it in a new window. I don't want the comments or the faces or the count, just the button and when clicked I don't want the option to add a comment. It just likes the page and opens it in a new tab, nothing more.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You can find answer for your question . Simply select the Layout to box_count or button_count . You will get simple like button .

Comment: no, i don't want the count, just the button and I want it to not give you the option of posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the facebook like plugin, the only customizations you can do are available here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

This will also generate the code on html5/iframe/xfbml into your application.

Comment: yeah I've been here, that's where I got the original button from, but I don't want the options it gives me, hence why I posted a question here on how to customize it.